# Binary Files on 32bit / 64bit systems?

Tags: python, serialization, 32bit-64bit

I am using `python` struct module to create custom binary files.

The file itself has the following format:

`4 bytes` (integer)
`1 byte` (unsigned char)
`4 bytes` (float)

`4 bytes` (integer)
`1 byte` (unsigned char)
`4 bytes` (float)

.......................... (**100000 such lines**)

`4 bytes` (integer)
`1 byte` (unsigned char)
`4 bytes` (float)

---

Currently, I am using a *32bit machine* to create these custom binary files. I am soon planning on switching to a *64bit machine*.

Will I be able to read/write the same files using both `{32bit / 64bit}` machines? or should I expect compatibility issues?

(I will be using Ubuntu Linux for both)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your struct format string uses "standard size and alignment" (`<` or `>`) rather than "native size and alignment" (`@`), your files can be used cross-platform.

Answer (score 1):

See http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment

> By default, C types are represented in the machine’s native format and byte order, and properly aligned by skipping pad bytes if necessary (according to the rules used by the C compiler).

So it depends on your code if it's portable or not.

Answer (score 1):

You have more to worry about than 32-bit vs. 64-bit.  The broad category you are talking about is called *serialization*.

Have a look at the [marshal](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/marshal.html) and/or [pickle](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/pickle.html) modules.

Comment: thank you. I am creating my own format. If I can read/write both files using 32/64bit systems -- why should I worry about `marshal` or `pickle`?

Comment: If all you care about is x86 vs. x86_64, then of course you can roll your own solution.  But if you use a standard marshalling mechanism --that worries about byte order and floating-point representations as well as word size -- you can be sure your code will port to any system in the future.  And the amount of code you have to write will be about the same; maybe even less.  So the question is, why _wouldn't_ you make your external format well-specified and use proper marshaling?